# How to instigate action when input is checked in SCSS?

Tags: html, checkbox, sass

Its very simply and I have looked at all these examples but still am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong!

I have created a custom checkbox, increased the size and style, and when it is clicked I want the letter "A" to appear in the box, but it simply will not respond, maybe a second pair of eyes will help me identify the problem.

below is my html and css:

```css
.container {
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;

    input,
    label {
        display: inline-block;
    }

    input {
        // opacity: 0;
        position: absolute;
        height: unset;
        width: unset;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    label::before {
        border: 1px solid #333;
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        font: 16px/1em sans-serif;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0 .25em 0 0;
        padding: 0;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 50px;
        border-radius: 5px;
        color: red;
        font-size: 50px;
        padding: 10px;
    }

    input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label::before {
        content: "A"; //code for checked
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <label for="form_agreeTerms" class="required">Agree terms</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="form_agreeTerms" name="form[agreeTerms]" required="required" value="1">          
    </div>
</div>
```

Here it is in [codepen](https://codepen.io/pw17l008/pen/mgXRYg?editors=1100)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You using the `+` operator, which means "The next sibling element".

You must move the label to be after the checkbox.

```
<div class="container">
    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" id="form_agreeTerms" name="form[agreeTerms]" required="required" value="1">   
        <label for="form_agreeTerms" class="required">Agree terms</label>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: okay okay that makes sense! Is there a way of saying "the previous sibling"? I can't change the html, SCSS is my only option!

Comment: You must move the label to be after the checkbox and set left to 170px in input css block.

Comment: @kontenurban CSS is applied to the DOM in a single pass. Because of this, there is no way of going back with CSS - so no previous sibling, and no parent element selection.